# Unwanted secondary namenode on my hadoop cluster

Tags: hadoop

I'm learning `Hadoop-2.9.2` especially on namenode HA.

At the first time of cluster setting, I put `dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address` into `hdfs-site.xml` and it works properly.

After reading [this](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-hdfs/HDFSHighAvailabilityWithQJM.html), I found out there is no need of secondary namenode under hadoop HA.

> Note that, in an HA cluster, the Standby NameNode also performs
>   checkpoints of the namespace state, and thus it is not necessary to
>   run a Secondary NameNode, CheckpointNode, or BackupNode in an HA
>   cluster. In fact, to do so would be an error. This also allows one who
>   is reconfiguring a non-HA-enabled HDFS cluster to be HA-enabled to
>   reuse the hardware which they had previously dedicated to the
>   Secondary NameNode.

finally, I removed `dfs.namenode.secondary.http-address` from hdfs.site.xml and restarted the cluster but `secondarynamenode` on `0.0.0.0` is still there.

here is my hdfs-site.xml below.

```
<configuration>
    <property>
            <name>dfs.namenode.name.dir</name>
            <value>/home/hadoop/data/nameNode</value>

            <name>dfs.datanode.data.dir</name>
            <value>/home/hadoop/data/datanode</value>

            <name>dfs.replication</name>
            <value>1</value>

    </property>
</configuration>
```

`hdfs` command shows me the same like below.

```
$ hdfs getconf -secondarynamenodes
18/12/21 00:35:43 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
0.0.0.0
```

I ensure that all config files are synchronized across all nodes.

According to my understanding, I need to get gid of `secondarynamenode` before getting into HA setting.

If I'm not wrong, How can I handle with this?

I do know that I can do `hadoop-daemon.sh stop secondarynamenode` but I don't want it to start at `start-dfs.sh`.

Comment: I would recommend using Apache Ambari for setting up a HA Hadoop cluster and getting the configs correct